# Update is_required for Existing Attribute Code

Tags: attributes, upgrade

I am thinking to update is_required data to "1" for existing "Region" attribute code.

```
select * From eav_attribute where attribute_id = '28'
```

However, I am wondering what is the practice here. Is it simply creating SQL statement and update that specific record in setup script fine? Or perhaps there may be a better way.

Comment: Which region attribute? for order or address?

Comment: for order and address =)

Comment: ok I have already added code in below answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create sql script to update region attribute

```
$installer->startSetup();
/*** Update customer address attributes*/
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'region', 'is_required', true); 

/*** Update order address attributes*/
$installer->updateAttribute('order_address', 'region', 'is_required', true);  
$installer->endSetup();
```

I hope above code will help

Comment: Can you please explain it in deep with example.

Answer (score 4):

I am writing this updates is simply sharing my research and hope could help someone out there.

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Package_Module>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </Package_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Package_Module</module>
                    <!-- 
                     Create a Switchable Installer Script 
                     This class is incredibly handy in case you need different setup classes 
                     -->
                    <class>Package_Module_Model_Resource_Setup</class> 
                </setup>
            </module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
<config>
```

**Custom Setup Class: Package_Module_Model_Resource_Setup**

```
class Package_Module_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
{
    public function getCatalogResourceSetup()
    {
        return new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup('module_setup');
    }
    public function getCustomerResourceSetup()
    {
        return new Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup('module_setup');
    }
    public function getCustomerEntitySetup() 
    {
        return new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('module_setup');
    }
}
```

**Upgrade Script: mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php**

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Package_Module_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this->getCustomerEntitySetup();

$installer->startSetup();
/*** Update customer address attributes*/
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'region', 'is_required', 1);

$installer->endSetup();
```

*Hereby a great article that shared about 'Switchable Installer Script'. Source link: [inchoo.net](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-switchable-install-script-setup-class/)*

Answer (score 0):

Create sql update script and run updateAttribute function.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('entity_type', 'your_attribute_id', 'required', 1);
$installer->endSetup();
```

With this function you can update any attribute's property.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying some scripts found, but the attribute still was required.  The correct parameter is 'is_required' and not 'required'.

`$installer->updateAttribute('entity_type', 'your_attribute_id', 'is_required', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Below code will update attribute using sql script

```
$installer = $this;
$this->updateAttribute('customer_address', 'region', 'is_required' ,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find definition of updateAttribute() function in file `app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\setup.php`